# Jade outputting raw HTML inside <pre> tags

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I am new to using jade and have this simple script:

```
extends layout 

block page
    - var menu = 'events' 

block content
    div event
        each item in events
            | Event name: #{item.name} Venue: #{item.venue}  Drink Price Score: #{item.drink_prices}
```

Which I expect to output as:

```
Event name: example Venue: The ex. Drink Price Score: 7
```

With some header and footer content above and below.

However the following is output:

[image]

When I check the Chrome Inspector the code is put as a *string* between 'pre' tags.

[image]

Why is this happening and how do I get this to render normally? Thanks!

**EDIT** SOLUTION

The error was occuring in my controller code event.js

```
exports.list = function(req, res, next) { 
req.models.Event.list(function(error, events) {
    if (error) return next(error);
//  res.send({events:events});         <-- offending line 
    res.render('event', { events: events } ); 
});
};
```

Comment: What is the output you are expecting? because since you have h2 the output is definitely going to be what you have mentioned. DO you want everything in one para or h2? please state your problem

Comment: Hey Darshan, it's outputting raw html tags which I don't want

Comment: Do you want your output to be <pre>Event name: example Venue: The ex. Drink Price Score: 7</pre>

Comment: Well what else would it output? Jade compiles to HTML. It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the output you want:

> Event name: example Venue: The ex. Drink Price Score: 7

Then this is the code you need

```
each item in events
  | Event name: #{item.name} Venue: #{item.venue} Drink Price Score: #{item.drink_prices}
```

You put `h2` tags on each line, so of course it's going to spit out each line wrapped in `<h2>` tags. I'm not sure why you expected differently.

The jade language is just an abstraction over HTML and the Jade compiler spits out HTML to be rendered by the browser. Jade is not the browser and browsers don't understand Jade code. Jade isn't going to read the Jade code and present you with a pretty page. It's going to spit out HTML that the browser *does* understand. Jade is just there to help you write cleaner looking HTML, then the Jade compiler turns the Jade document into an HTML document that the browser knows how to render.

Comment: Thanks for answering, your answer worked for that snippet, i've edited my question to include the extends and block tags and the output is being rendered within <pre> tags again. Is there anything you can point me towards to explain this?

Comment: We would really need to see your full code. Including the layout file and the controller logic that is rendering the view.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Chev, I updated my answer with the solution! :D